# KnockoutJS + Validation: binding number of validation errors

Tags: javascript, validation, data-binding, knockout.js

Please check the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhulshof/6bd4g/4/

I'm experiencing 2 problems which I just can't solve:

1. I'm unable to display the number of validation errors in the View. `Self.errors()` doesn't seem to be an observable. **Edit::** It works for the initial `self.articles()` rows; but just not for the rows added to the DOM later.
2. When adding two or more rows (articles), it says I have more validation errors than it actually has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial answer, you need to modify your validation configuration object

```
ko.validation.configure({
    decorateElement        : true,
    errorElementClass      : 'error',
    insertMessages         : true,  // had been set to false.
    parseInputAttributes   : true
});
```

That will cause the messages to occur.

I'm not very familiar with the the knockout validation plug in, but once it has an error, the count doesn't go below 1 for some reason.  Not sure why that is happening.

---

**EDIT**

The count of error messages being off by 1 is a bug.  The first error message in the message list is "*null*".  It is discussed in issues log at https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues/99

Comment: Thank you for your post. Changing the insertMessages parameter gives me the "This field is required" messages. That's not what I was looking for. I want to bind the number of errors (as stored in self.errors().length) to: <span data-bind="text: errors().length"></span>

Comment: Found your problem with Problem #1.  In your add function, you are redefining self.errors.  When you do this, the original function for self.errors remains bound to the html element that displays the count.  Your new self.errors() is now not bound to any html control.  Not sure what the correct fix, but this is the source of your errors.